# Header Type change to application/json not changing

Tags: php, api, rest, mobile

header type of the
response from *"text/html"* to *"application/json".* Other then this

am using as header type as 
header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")

But not change.

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 19 Nov 2014 05:49:55 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
Vary: User-Agent
Via: 1.1 (external)pdc.amw.lan (squid/3.3.8), 1.1 (frontal)pdc.amw.lan (squid/3.3.8)
X-Cache: MISS from (external)pdc.amw.lan, MISS from (frontal)pdc.amw.lan
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from (external)pdc.amw.lan:3130, MISS from (frontal)pdc.amw.lan:0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set header as follows, not like `header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")`

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: now i add header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"); but till i not get solution. same result occurred in my server. but its working in my localhost.

Comment: show your php code where you are setting header, try omitting `;charset=UTF-8` and see

Comment: am use this in config.php              <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usename", "pwd", "db");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "usename", "password", "db");
?>

Comment: dont post your password here, where is the `json_encode()` for returned db result

Comment: i have used the json_encode() in my another php file. above files is config.php

Comment: post your json_encode file code in question and please delete your config.php comment, its contains sensitive info